# Possible to fetch authData in Parse database?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I linked the user with their Facebook account with `linkUserInBackground`, and their Facebook ID is stored under `authData` inside the **Parse.co**m database. I want to access this particular Facebook ID to retrieve the user's profile picture. Is this possible? If it is, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are nothing to do with **Parse.com**, their linking function is just for logging user in.

You can call API from Facebook iOS SDK in order to [get that image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/).

**EDIT:**
Although you use your Facebook ID to log in, you won't get the `authData` back when you query for it. So, the best way to do is to have your own custom field to store the Facebook ID so that it's available for you when you fetch it.

[Extremely helpful documentation](https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-id-of-a-user-logged-in-with-facebook) for getting Facebook ID after logging in:

Comment: This didn't really answer my question. I was wondering if I could access the authData column in my Parse database. It makes it a lot easier for me if I can access the Facebook ID.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I access the user's Facebook ID?